# Asynchronous execution of functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-deferred

I want to call two function say function `a()` and function `b()` in parallel. These functions are independent to each other, and lets say the time required to execute these two functions are not fixed. Sometimes function `a()` will take more time than function `b()` and vice versa.  But there is another function `c()` that should only execute when both the functions `a()` and `b()` are completed.

How should I do this using jQuery's Deferred object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018931/jquery-custom-deferred-functions Check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can make the `a()` and `b()` functions return deferred objects which you `resolve()` once their logic has completed. You can then run `c()` once both previous functions have completed. Try this:

```js
function a() {
  var aDef = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    aDef.resolve('a done');
  }, 1000);
  return aDef;
}

function b() {
  var bDef = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    bDef.resolve('b done');
  }, 3000);
  return bDef;
}

function c() {
  console.log('all done!')
}

console.log('running...');
$.when(a(), b()).done(function(a, b) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  c();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: cannot compete with a 193k user... i was too slow to answer :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a global variable to determ an operational status and execute a polling each 100 milliseconds (or each milliseconds if you need).

```js
var myStatus = {
  "a": false,
  "b": false
};

function a() {
  myStatus["a"] = true;
  console.log(myStatus['a']);
}

function b() {
  myStatus["b"] = true;
}

function getStatusText() {
  var s = 'not complete';
  if (myStatus.a && myStatus.b) {
    s = 'all complete';
  } else {
    if (myStatus.a) {
      s = 'a complete';
    }
    if (myStatus.b) {
      s = 'b complete';
    }
  }
  return s;
}

function c() {
  //check operational status
  var statusText = getStatusText();
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = statusText;
}
setInterval(
  function() {
    c()
  }, 100);
```

```html
<button onclick="a()">Set a() complete</button><button onclick="b()">Set b() complete</button>

<p>operational status <span id="status"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Jquery defer and promise method to handle calls.

https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/ or

https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to the question.  I don't use defer or anything like it.

But I want to show something I do quite often: add a onReady callback, as a parameter to a() and b().  I add these callbacks to any self-written-function that takes time to execute.

```
function a(onready) {
  // let's say we get Ajax data
  $.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#message').html(data);
      if(typeof onready == 'function') {
        onready();   // you might also want to add message as a parameter, like onready(data), or anready('Data okay'), ...
      }
    }
  });
}

function b(onready) {
  // let's say we sort <table> rows
  sortTable('my_table', 'my_row', 'ASC');  // this function (not provided here) is not asynchronous, it just takes time before it's done
  if(typeof onready == 'function') {
    onready();   
  }
}

function c() {
  alert('Yippy!');
}

$(document).ready(function() {  // or this could be after the client clicks on a button, or so
  var aReady = false;
  var bReady = false;

  a(function() {
    aReady = true;
    if(aReady && bReady) {
      c();
    }
  });

  b(function() {
    bReady = true;
    if(aReady && bReady) {
      c();
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery.when() to do this. Please read the document about this at  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

```
a = function () {
//your code for function a
}
b = function () {
//your code for function b
}

$.when( a(), b() ).done(function c() {
    //your code for function c
});
```